# How to do many to one relationship in Django

Tags: python, django

I am doing a many to one relationship but I get a prompt that the field person in the report is without a default.

I tried setting the default to an empty space, I get an IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed

```
class Person(models.Model):
    person_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    person_location = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)


classReport (models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        Person, related_name='people', default="", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: You seem to know about the `null` option to a field since you use it for `person_location`. If you want `Report.person` to be nullable would it make sense to use it there, too? (Side note: I strongly advise against the `person_` and `product_` field name prefixes you have there. Those are fields of their respective classes; the person / product relationship should be clear from that.)

Comment: Are you adding the Report model and getting the error from migrations?

Comment: `default=""` should only be used on a character-type field, not a `ForeignKey` field.

Comment: @IainShelvington yes

Comment: @DanSwain Thanks